# Can't use System.Windows.Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wcf, nhibernate

I was trying to add System.Windows.Application to my c# project and will gives me an error. please help me to figure it out.

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 **using Application = System.Windows.Application;**

 namespace DIPS.DocumentPublish.Admin.Helpers{
    public class DocumentPublishClientAdminNotificationService{
       public void Invoke(Action action)
       {
           if (action == null)
           {
               return;
           }

           if (IsInvokeRequired())
           {
               if (Application.Current?.Dispatcher != null)
               {
                   Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(action);
                   return;
               }
           }
           action();
       }
    }
 }
```

error is The type or namespace name 'Application does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'(Are you missing an assembly reference?)
cannot resolve 'Application'

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: edited the question with an error

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=netcore-3.1) is the class you're after, right? You should have a reference to that assembly built-in.

Comment: @User01 Please show the references of your project.

Comment: You have a reference to winforms in there. If it's wpf you shouldn't. Is this not a wpf project? Do you have an app.xaml and a wpf mainwindow?

Comment: Why not simple `using System.Windows;`?

Comment: Hi, is the problem resolved? If the problem persists, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a PresentationFramework reference in the project:

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Application` as the alias name, because it conflicts with the static class in the `System` namespace. Either use a different name (`App`, etc) or remove the using statement for System.

Comment: I tried it, but the same result, is there any reference to add for the project?